¿Cómo optimizar la sintaxis de un if presente en un for de Python?
for juego in carrito:
            if juego['codigo'] == codi_juego:#es una variable que representa cada elemento de la lista 
                juego_a_eliminar = juego
                break

Necesito optimizar la sintaxis de esa parte de un código que creamos para un certamen la cual está dentro del siguiente def:
def eliminar():
    ver_carrito()
    try:
        codi_juego = int(input("Ingrese el código del juego que desea eliminar: "))
        juego_a_eliminar = None #definimos una variable vacia para luego definrla como el juego a eliminar
        for juego in carrito:
            if juego['codigo'] == codi_juego:#es una variable que representa cada elemento de la lista
                juego_a_eliminar = juego
                break #asegura que solo el primer juego que coincide con el código será asignado a juego_a_eliminar
        if juego_a_eliminar: # si el carrito tiene algo que eliminar es True
            carrito.remove(juego_a_eliminar) #.remove elmimina lo que esta entre parentecis la lista carrito
            print(f"{juego_a_eliminar['nombre']} ha sido eliminado del carrito.")
        else:
            print("Juego no encontrado en el carrito.")
            eliminar()
        return#################### 
    except ValueError:
        print("Error: Ingrese un código válido.")
        eliminar()


Sería útil que mostraras la definición de carrito

También muestra la definición de juego

El ciclo y el condicional no los vas a poder simplificar, no sin modificar el contenedor y/o los objetos que representan cada juego (supongo que un diccionario). Lo que si puedes es simplificar el proceso de eliminación que sigues.
Realmente no necesitas usar la variable auxiliar juego_a_eliminar y todo lo que viene después para diferir la eliminación. Es cierto que, como norma general, no se debe modificar un iterable mientras se itera sobre el mismo ya que se invalida el iterador, pero en este caso eso es irrelevante ya que rompes el ciclo justo cuando encuentras el item a eliminar.
También puedes considerar eliminar la recursividad y usar una implementación iterativa, generalmente más eficiente y legible, aunque esto es subjetivo.
def eliminar():
    while True:
        try:
            codigo_juego = int(input("Ingrese el código del juego que desea eliminar: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Error: Ingrese un código válido.")
            continue
            
        for juego in carrito:
            if juego['codigo'] == codigo_juego:
                carrito.remove(juego)
                print(f"{juego['nombre']} ha sido eliminado del carrito.")
                return
                
        print("Juego no encontrado en el carrito.")

Si como supongo carrito es una lista, otra optimización que puedes hacer es prescindir de list.remove() ya que dicho método necesita iterar de nuevo sobre la lista y comparar cada item con el pasado como argumento. La posición del item a eliminar la puedes obtener de forma simple usando enumerate() y luego usar del para eliminar el item usando su indice:
def eliminar():
    while True:
        try:
            codigo_juego = int(input("Ingrese el código del juego que desea eliminar: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Error: Ingrese un código válido.")
            continue
    
        for indice, juego in enumerate(carrito):
            if juego['codigo'] == codigo_juego:
                del carrito[indice]
                print(f"{juego['nombre']} ha sido eliminado del carrito.")
                return
    
        print("Juego no encontrado en el carrito.")

Ten en cuenta que si carrito está vacía no hay forma de salir de la función. De ser posible llamar a la función en este caso, deberias manejarlo en ella.

Muchas gracias <3
